# combine sed and sort commands in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this bash commands to filter words in a text file (file1 in the example)

Until now i have to use two separate commands to get the result i want

```
sed -n "SAMPLETEXT" file1 > file2
sort file2 | uniq -c > file2.tmp && mv file2.tmp file2.txt
```

because i need to filter out lines with certain strings from file1 and then count all equal lines.

is there a way to do that all in one command to show the output in the console so that i dont need to even create a "file2"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n "SAMPLETEXT" file1|sort| uniq -c
```

Comment: You are welcome. if it helped, you can upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep too:

```
grep "SAMPLETEXT" file1 | sort | uniq -c
```